# Electron secondary window not receiving IPC messages

Tags: javascript, typescript, electron

In my typescript which is attached to the HTML being run by my app, I am creating a new window for my settings.  From what I can tell, the preloaded script is also being loaded onto the new window once it's opened, but the window isn't receiving IPC messages from the main script.

Here is the preloaded script:

```
const { contextBridge, ipcRenderer } = require("electron");

console.log("preloaded!");

contextBridge.exposeInMainWorld("api", {
  send: (channel, data) => {
    let validChannels = ["toMain", "select-dirs", "toSettings", "fromSettings"];
    if (validChannels.includes(channel)) {
      ipcRenderer.send(channel, data);
    }
  },
  receive: (channel, func) => {
    let validChannels = ["fromMain", "toSettings", "fromSettings"];
    if (validChannels.includes(channel)) {
      ipcRenderer.on(channel, (event, ...args) => func(...args));
    }
  },
});
```

And here is the typescript file that I've attached to the second window's HTML.

```
(<any>window).api.receive("toSettings", (data: any) => {
  console.log(data);
})

var closeButton: HTMLButtonElement;

var settings = "";
var settignsDir = "";

document.onreadystatechange = () => {
  if (document.readyState == "interactive") {
    (<any>window).api.send("fromSettings", "ready")
    closeButton = <HTMLButtonElement>document.getElementById("closeButton");

    closeButton.addEventListener("click", () => {
      (<any>window).api.send("toMain", "refresh");
      self.close();
    });
  }
};
```

I'm using the same preloaded script for my renderer and using the same receiving code, it's working just fine.  And from the second window's typescript, I can properly send IPC messages to the main process.  But I can't receive any messages on the second window.  I'm thinking I need to re-preload the file directly to the second window via the features array in `window.open()`.  Oh and here's the code that is opening the settings window.

```
window.open(
          "./html/settings.html",
          "_blank",
          "top=200,left=600,frame=false,nodeIntegration=no"
        );
```

According to the Electron documentation, you can also include a preload in the third-string but I can't figure out how as the documentation fails to have an example and I can't find one anywhere.

In response to Kdau:

Here is the requested code:

```
(<any>window).api.receive("fromSettings", (data: any) => {
  (<any>window).api.send("toSettings", "WHAT!");
})
```

I was mainly using it to see if the settings or child window as you called it was receiving the message.  If you could clarify what you mean by address to the child window because I thought that the preload script should be automatically parsing, "ok so this channel needs to go to this receiver".

I would like to point out that in the code snippet that you included returns this error:
Argument of type '({ url }: HandlerDetails) => { frame: boolean; webPreferences: { nodeIntegration: boolean; preload: string; }; } | undefined' is not assignable to parameter of type '(details: HandlerDetails) => { action: "deny"; } | { action: "allow"; overrideBrowserWindowOptions?: BrowserWindowConstructorOptions | undefined; }'.
Type '{ frame: boolean; webPreferences: { nodeIntegration: boolean; preload: string; }; } | undefined' is not assignable to type '{ action: "deny"; } | { action: "allow"; overrideBrowserWindowOptions?: BrowserWindowConstructorOptions | undefined; }'.
Type 'undefined' is not assignable to type '{ action: "deny"; } | { action: "allow"; overrideBrowserWindowOptions?: BrowserWindowConstructorOptions | undefined; }'.

I don't know what to do with this.

Answer (score 0):

While you can pass a preload in the third argument, the more flexible and reliable approach is to use [`setWindowOpenHandler`](https://www.electronjs.org/docs/api/web-contents#contentssetwindowopenhandlerhandler). So, just after constructing your main window (assuming the variable is `mainWindow`):

```js
mainWindow.webContents.setWindowOpenHandler(({ url }) => {
  if (url === './html/settings.html') {
    return {
      action: 'allow',
      overrideBrowserWindowOptions: {
        frame: false,
        webPreferences: {
          nodeIntegration: false,
          preload: 'my-child-window-preload-script.js'
        }
      }
    }
  }
})
```

However, most (all??) options are inherited from the parent window anyway, and I would imagine that your `preload` has been inherited and that is why you can send messages from the child window.

As for not receiving messages in the child window, the messages aren't being addressed to that window's `webContents` by your code. Sending to the main window's `webContents` won't work. Unfortunately, the IPC in Electron isn't a broadcast system where every process receives every message filtered only by channel. The channel feature sits on top of process-based targeting. Each render process can only send messages to the main process, and the main process must address one specific render process at a time when sending.

So, to communicate between two render processes, use the main process as a relay. In the main process, to get the `webContents` of a window that was opened through `window.open`, you can listen for a message from that process (such as one you send as soon as it loads) and/or call `webContents.getAllWebContents()` and iterate through to find the right one.

Comment: I included the requested code in an edit on the bottom of my question.  And yeah it is inheriting the preload script after I included the print statement in the preload script and it showed up in the console of the child window.  I really appreciate you giving an example for the set window open handler as well because electron's documentation is kinda ass in my opinion

Comment: @MCRM Oops! It looks like one page of Electron's docs show an outdated way of calling `setWindowOpenHandler`. I switched my answer to the current API. (As you said, the docs have some issues.) I also expanded my answer to explain Electron's IPC model more, with the approach you'll need to take to relay between renderers.

Comment: @MCRM One last note: While submitting a fix to that error in the Electron docs, I noticed that the inheritance of non-security-related options by child windows is going to be removed in the next major version.